# Неправильный вывод текста в QTextEdit в игре "Быки и коровы"

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pyqt, qt-designer, qtextedit

У меня есть код игры "Быки и коровы" и интерфейс игры. 
При нажатии кнопки запускается игра и в начале должен вывестись текст в `textEdit`, но он выводится когда заканчивается игра.

Вопрос как вывести текст в начале игры в `textEdit` ?

**main.py**:

```
import sys 
import os
from interwes import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.exit)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.restart)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.start_game)

    
    # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется
    # при нажатии на кнопку                  
    def exit(self):
        sys.exit(0)

    def restart(self):
        os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
    
    def start_game(self):
        import random


    #создавая список все возможных ответов 
    def get_all_answers():
        ans = []
        for x in range(10000):
            tmp = str(x).zfill(4)

            lst = ['x' for num in tmp if tmp.count(num)==1]
            if len(lst)==4:
                ans.append(list(map(int,tmp)))
        
        #print(ans)    
        return ans     

    
    # выбирает один ответ из списка возможных
    def get_one_answer(ans):
        num = random.choice(ans)
        return num


    # запрашиваем у пользователя неповторяющиеся цифры
    def input_number():
        while True:
            nums = input("Введите 4 неповторяющиеся цифры: ")
            if len(nums)!= 4 or not nums.isdigit():
                continue
    
            nums=list(map(int,nums))
    
            if len(set(nums))==4:
                break
        return nums

    
    # сравнивает два числа и сообщает количество быков и коров
    def check(nums,true_nums):
        bulls,cows=0,0

        for x,num in enumerate(nums):
            if num in true_nums:
        
                if nums[x] == true_nums[x]:
                   bulls += 1
        
                else:
                    cows += 1
        return bulls, cows


    # удаляет неподходящие варианты из списка возможно
    def del_bad_answers(ans,enemy_try,bull,cow):
        for num in ans[:]:
            temp_bull,temp_cow = check(num,enemy_try)
            if temp_bull != bull or temp_cow != cow:
                ans.remove(num)

        return ans
    
    self.ui.textEdit.setText("Игра быки и коровы")

    answers=get_all_answers()
    player=input_number()
    enemy=get_one_answer(answers)

    while True:
        print('='* 15 ,'ход игрока' ,'=' *15)
        print("Угадайте число компьютера")
        number=input_number()
        bulls,cows=check(number,enemy)
        print("Быки: ",bulls,"Коровы: ",cows)

        if bulls==4:
            print("Победил игрок")
            print("Компьютер загадал число:",enemy)
            break


        print('=' * 15 , "Ход компьютера" , '=' * 15)
        enemy_try=get_one_answer(answers)
        print("Компьютер считает, что вы загадали число ", enemy_try)
        bulls,cows=check(enemy_try,player)
        print("Быки: ",bulls,"Коровы: ",cows)

        if bulls==4:
            print("Победил компьютер")
            print("Компьютер загадал число:",enemy)
            break
        else:
            answers = del_bad_answers(answers,enemy_try,bulls,cows)
    

if __name__=="__main__":
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   myapp = MyWin()
   myapp.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**interwes.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
       MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
       MainWindow.resize(489, 481)
       self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
       self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
       self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
       self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 491, 51))
       self.label.setObjectName("label")
       self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
       self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 91, 23))
       self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
       self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
       self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 100, 221, 21))
       self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
       self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
       self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 140, 113, 20))
       self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
       self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
       self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 270, 113, 20))
       self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
       self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
       self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 230, 191, 16))
       self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
       self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
       self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 180, 201, 21))
       self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
       self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
       self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 60, 101, 23))
       self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
       self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
       self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 310, 291, 121))
       self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
       self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
       self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 60, 101, 23))
       self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
       MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
       self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
       self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 489, 21))
       self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
       MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
       self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
       self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
       MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

       self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
       QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

     def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p> 
        <span style=\" font-size:18pt;\">Добро пожаловать в игру &quot;Быки и 
        коровы&quot;</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " выйти иг игры"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p> 
        <span style=\" font-size:11pt;\">введите свое число из 4 цифр</span> 
        </p></body></html>"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p> 
        <span style=\" font-size:11pt;\">введите число из 4 цыфр</span></p> 
        </body></html>"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p> 
        <span style=\" font-size:11pt;\">угадайте число компьютера</span></p> 
        </body></html>"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "новая игра"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "начать игру"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = Ui_MainWindow()
   ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
   MainWindow.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Отформатиируйте пожалуйста свой код правильно и предоставьте модуль, который содержит класс `Ui_MainWindow`

Comment: @ S. Nick готово

Comment: Уже немного лучше, а модуль `interwes.py`    предоставите ?

Comment: @ S. Nick смотрите

Comment: @ S.Nick готово

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извините, я совсем непонял вашей логики. Что-то выкинул, что-то добавил. Попробуйте проанализировать пример и додавить что вам надо.

main.py

```
import sys 
import os
import random
from interwes import Ui_MainWindow #*
from PyQt5    import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
#        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.exit)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.restart)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.start_game)

        self.ui.textEdit.setText("Игра быки и коровы\n")

    # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется
    # при нажатии на кнопку                  
    def exit(self):
        sys.exit(0)

    # ??????????????????????  
    def restart(self):
        os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)

    def start_game(self):
        self.answers = get_all_answers()
        self.player  = input_number(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), 1)
        if isinstance(self.player, str):
            self.ui.textEdit.append(self.player)
            return False

        self.enemy   = get_one_answer(self.answers)

        self.go_game()

    # +++ "Угадайте число компьютера"
    def go_game(self):
        self.number  = input_number(self.ui.lineEdit_3.text(), 2)
        if isinstance(self.number, str):
            self.ui.textEdit.append(self.number)
            return False    

        bulls, cows = check(self.number, self.enemy)
        self.ui.textEdit.append("Быки: {}, Коровы: {}".format(bulls, cows))
        if bulls == 4:
            self.ui.textEdit.append("Победил игрок")
            self.ui.textEdit.append("Компьютер загадал число: {} ".format(self.enemy))    
            return True

        enemy_try = get_one_answer(self.answers)
        self.ui.textEdit.append("Компьютер считает, что вы загадали число {}".format(enemy_try))
        bulls, cows = check(enemy_try, self.player)
        self.ui.textEdit.append("Быки: {}, Коровы: {}".format(bulls, cows))

        if bulls == 4:
            self.ui.textEdit.append("Победил компьютер")
            self.ui.textEdit.append("Компьютер загадал число: {} ".format(self.enemy))    
            return True    
        else:
            #answers = del_bad_answers(answers, enemy_try, bulls, cows)            
            self.ui.textEdit.append("\n Игра закончена ??? Никто не выграл ???\n")
            self.ui.lineEdit.setText("")
            self.ui.lineEdit_3.setText("")



#-----------------------------------------------------------
# сравнивает два числа и сообщает количество быков и коров
def check(nums, true_nums):
    bulls, cows = 0, 0
    for x,num in enumerate(nums):
        if num in true_nums:
            if nums[x] == true_nums[x]:
               bulls += 1
            else:
                cows += 1
    return bulls, cows

# ??????/ удаляет неподходящие варианты из списка возможно
#def del_bad_answers(ans, enemy_try, bull, cow):
#    for num in ans[:]:
#        temp_bull, temp_cow = check(num,enemy_try)
#        if temp_bull != bull or temp_cow != cow:
#            ans.remove(num)
#    return ans

def get_all_answers():
    ans = []
    for x in range(10000):
        tmp = str(x).zfill(4)

        lst = ['x' for num in tmp if tmp.count(num)==1]
        if len(lst)==4:
            ans.append(list(map(int,tmp)))

    return ans  

# запрашиваем у пользователя неповторяющееся цифры
def input_number(nums, fl): #(lineEditText):
    if len(nums)!= 4 or not nums.isdigit():
        nums = "введите СВОЕ число из 4 цифр" if fl==1 else "введите число из 4 цыфр"
        return nums        

    nums = list(map(int,nums))     # ???

    if len(set(nums)) != 4:
        nums = "введите СВОЕ число из 4 цифр" if fl==1 else "введите число из 4 цыфр"
    return nums

# вибирает один ответ из спика возможных
def get_one_answer(ans):
    num = random.choice(ans)
    return num


if __name__=="__main__":
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   myapp = MyWin()
   myapp.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

interwes.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(489, 481)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 491, 51))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 100, 221, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 140, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 270, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 230, 191, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 180, 201, 21))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 60, 101, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 310, 311, 121))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")

        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 60, 101, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 489, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", '''<html><head/><body><p> 
        <span style=\" font-size:18pt;\">Добро пожаловать в игру &quot;Быки и 
        коровы&quot;</span></p></body></html>'''))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " выйти иг игры"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", '''<html><head/><body><p> 
        <span style=\" font-size:11pt;\">введите свое число из 4 цифр</span> 
        </p></body></html>'''))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", '''<html><head/><body><p> 
        <span style=\" font-size:11pt;\">введите число из 4 цыфр</span></p> 
        </body></html>'''))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", '''<html><head/><body><p> 
        <span style=\" font-size:11pt;\">угадайте число компьютера</span></p> 
        </body></html>'''))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "новая игра"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "начать игру"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ S. Nick игра не закончена, игра быки и коровы заканчивается тогда кто то то отгадывает число противника.